# timer in python code but like a montlyh subscription

Tags: python

I'm a new coder.

That's why I have a program that I want to ask, but I need to create a timer and the program should not open when the timer is finished, how can I do this? Can you help me with this?

What should I try in this program and make a similar monthly subscription?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We cannot ["help you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) generally speaking - we require a *specific* question, which arises out of your best attempt to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem, attempt your own solution, [try to get it working](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and isolate any specific problems with a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

5 being the seconds waiting

Comment: this must be saved and when the exiting program must be saved, when it is opened again must be countdown

Comment: what about making it read a file and that file used to store the timer, as like date , sys info or just a file with the data for seconds remaining to count etc.